# Where should I go next?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Well, I think I have enough knowledge of cocoa that I can go learn another thing.  What would you recommend learning after learning cocoa?  (Ex. Core animation, OpenCL, core data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn [LISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29).

It is fundamentally different from pretty much every other programming language there is. It will force you to think of problems in new ways. Even if you never ever will use LISP in a real world project *(I never did)* you will become a much better programmer.

Anyone who wants to call themselves a programmer should known about *(spent at least a full week with)*:

- **C** - to know the heavy lifting and how it *actually works*.
- **LISP** - to understand functional programming.
- **Smalltalk/Objective-C** - to understand real object oriented programming.
- **Prolog** - to understand logic programming.

C++, and any language that derives its OOP design from it, is just C structs with function pointers. Yes Java and C# I look at you too.

Comment: um... how do you use LISP, or even compile it on a mac?

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer: You can get Ready Lisp here: http://www.newartisans.com/projects/ready-lisp.html Or as a selfish plug you can get dLISP that I wrote myself here: http://www.dsource.org/projects/dlisp (manual compile needed).

Answer (score 2):

I really depends what your goals are. If you want to stick to Objective-C, dive into Cocoa Touch if you haven't already. I'd also suggest checking out frameworks such as MacRuby if you want to stick to developing Mac apps, it is pretty sweet.
If you want to go somewhere totally different, I've been messing around with Rails and Android a lot recently.

Answer (score 1):

Learning PostScript is a good way to broaden your understanding of the drawing model also used by Quartz and AppKit, and can be useful for prototyping your drawing code.

Answer (score 0):

Learn another language. Maybe C/C++ since they are similar. Or maybe C#. Or you can try something completely different such as python, pascal, D or VB.

Answer (score 0):

depends what you aim for

but  if you are not strong in C/C++ I would suggest that. A) its what cocoa is based on B) if you want to port your code to other platforms, usually you'll have a good chance of reusing directly the C/C++ withou a lot of changes.

> (Ex. Core animation, OpenCL, core
>   data)

those are just tools, if you want to specialize in iphone then its good practice to look up the various feature, look at the examples and then implement a little example for yourself.

otherwise if you have no precise goal you can also go to the bookstore and pick a random book ^^